# Unwanted transition on :active css

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I've just started learning html & css and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing but..

I've added a :hover transition so that when I hover over my header "FIENDS" it fades from #000000 to #800000. Which I've implemented and which works. I've also added the css :active, so that when I click my header "FIENDS" it instantly switches from #800000 to #ffffff. But at the moment it isn't instantly switching, it seems to be using the transition I set up for the :hover and fading to #ffffff. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fiends</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Fiends" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="centertext"><fade>FIENDS</fade></h1>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background-color: #ffffff}

body {
    font-family: bebas neue;
    text-align: center;}

h1 {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 200px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;}

h1.centertext {
    margin: 225px auto auto auto}

fade { 
    color: #000000; 
    -webkit-transition: color .12s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .12s linear;
    -ms-transition: color .12s linear;
    -o-transition: color .12s linear;
    transition: color .12s linear;}

fade:hover {
    color: #800000;}

fade:active {
    color: #ffffff}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to use JavaScript to get the full animation effect that you want.  You can change the `transition` property in `:active`, for example:

```
fade:active {
    transition: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rppmd/

However the `transition` is not overridden when it is no longer active so the element will still fade back in (i.e. the solution is not perfect).

With JavaScript you can remove `transition` entirely and have JS do all the animations.  This will allow you to set the animation timing e.g. on hover.  On `mousedown` and `mouseup`, no animation would be needed, just color change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Forgive my ignorance, but what is JavaScript in relation to HTML & CSS? And how can I use the actions you suggested to achieve my goal?

Comment: @FiendTwo you're in for a lot of reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript